# Create a flowchart that will adequately represent the logic

Tags: pseudocode, flowchart

“For a salesman to determine their salary for the month at a given point during
the month, they will enter their basic salary, total sales and commission rate
into an application. The application will then calculate and display the
salesman’s salary by adding the salesman’s basic salary to the product of the
total sales that they had at the given point in time and the commission rate at
which they were appointed. The commission rate is expressed as a percentage.”

Answer (score 0):

The flowchart would look something like this:

[image: Flowchart]